# Instance on original points after subdivison

Tags: geometry-nodes

I need to instance on original points after subdivison surface.
Capture points(boolean) before subdivison and using them as "Instance on Points"->"Selection" doesn't seem to work.

How could I do it?

[image]

So I need this:
[image]

Instead of this:
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: i think this is quite difficult task because you don't know which were the "old" points and which were the new ones because there is no "connection" between them and they even don't have same positions or indices. So i think...it might be impossible. And the "original" points are NOT (!) on the same positions as after the subdiv node...

Comment: Thanks Chris. I think I found a solution, I posted it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution using sample Index(boolean) and using them as "Instance on Points"->"Selection"

[image]

[image]

Comment: nice!!!!!!!!!!!!!!